# Same Origin Third Party Scripts sameSite attributes sink lighthouse score. There must be some fix

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, github-pages, lighthouse, samesite, third-party-cookies

graphcomment.com is not a bad commenting system, quicker to implement than an opensource solution on github pages, and allows for guesting commenting.

Of course, like most third-party services once it's it wants to load a lot of resources and collect cookies without setting any decent sameSite attributes.

This destroys lighthouse scores on any page you add comments.

**Lighthouse score for project website without graphcomment:**

[image]

**Lighthouse score for project website with graphcomment:**

[image]

**How would you fix this?**

**Implement CSP strategy to block individual resources and run tests?**

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution then found code out there to help get it done.

Obviously, just lazy load the third-party script, in this case graph-comment's script.

I did it with window.requestAnimationFrame and an isElementInViewport function, because that's how I run animations in the viewport.

Then create a script element and inside of the check to see if script element exists, onload your third-party-scripts.

Works 100% (okay, 99%)

[image]